# ExtJS Infinite Scroll Grid with remote Filters and Sort

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, filtering, dom-events

In ExtJS 4.1 beta 2 I managed to implement an infinite scroll grid with a remote store. I basically took an existing (fully operational) paging grid (with remote store, filtering and sorting) and then put in the appropriate configs for infinite scrolling:

```
// Use a PagingGridScroller (this is interchangeable with a PagingToolbar)
verticalScrollerType: 'paginggridscroller',
// do not reset the scrollbar when the view refreshs
invalidateScrollerOnRefresh: false,
// infinite scrolling does not support selection
disableSelection: true,
```

It doesn't say this anywhere in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel)(see Infinite Scrolling section), but you need to set your store to have `buffered: true` config. And you can't load with `store.load()` it needs to be done like this:

```
store.prefetch({
    start: 0,
    limit: 200,
    callback: function() {
        store.guaranteeRange(0, 99);
    }
});
```

With all that, everything works great if I scroll slowly and thus allow the data to prefetch, don't use any filters and don't use any sorting.

However, if I scroll fast or try to make the infinite scroll grid reload with a filter active or while sorting it all breaks apart. Error is `options is undefined`.

I've spent a couple of hours doing some tracing in the code and googling and aside from concluding that no one has implemented an infinite scroll grid with remote filters and remote scrolling, I have found the following:

The filtering is breaking down because of this method in `Ext.data.Store` which is called by the infinite scroller when it needs more data from the server:

```
mask: function() {
    this.masked = true;   
    this.fireEvent('beforeload');
},
```

For some reason, this method fires the `beforeload` event **without** the `Ext.data.Operation` parameter which is supposed to be part of it as specified [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-beforeload).

As a result, an error occurs in the `onbeforeload` handler in `Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature` because of course "options" is undefined:

```
/**
 * @private
 * Handler for store's beforeload event when configured for remote filtering
 * @param {Object} store
 * @param {Object} options
 */
onBeforeLoad : function (store, options) {

    options.params = options.params || {};
    this.cleanParams(options.params);
    var params = this.buildQuery(this.getFilterData());
    Ext.apply(options.params, params);

},
```

I can cut out the call to this `mask` method from the PagingScroller code and then the scroll functionality is great. I can scroll as fast as I like and it loads the data properly. **But** then filters and sort does not get applied to the ajax requests.

I haven't dived as much into the sorting aspect but I think it something similar with this `mask` method because sort is simply another element contained by the `operation` object and it causes **no** operation object to be passed to the ajax request.

I'm thinking that if I could just figure out how to force the `mask` method to fire `beforeload` with the `operation` parameter (like the docs say it is supposed to) everything will be fine. Problem is, I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. Any suggestions?

If someone would just tell me that I am wrong and people have in fact made this work, I would be inspired, but a snippet of any overrides you used to handle this problem or a link would be much appreciated.

I've also tried downgrading to 4.0.7 and 4.0.2a and I get the same results, so it isn't just a beta problem.

**Update - 7 Feb 12:**

This seems like it may actually be a `Ext.ux.grid.FilterFeature` problem not an infinite scrolling problem. If I remove the FilterFeature config entirely infinite scrolling works great and does pass the sorting params to my backend when I sort by a column. I will start looking into the FilterFeature end of things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**SUCCESS!** I have infinite scrolling working with a remote filter and remote sort (this is in 4.1 beta 2, but because I was getting the same errors in 4.02a and 4.0.7 I imagine that it would resolve those too). Basically, I just had to add a few overrides in my code.

I haven't done testing in other browsers but I have it going in FF. Here are the overrides that I am using:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Store, {

    // Handle prefetch when all the data is there and add purging
    prefetchPage: function(page, options, forceLoad) {

        var me = this,
            pageSize = me.pageSize || 25,
            start = (page - 1) * me.pageSize,
            end = start + pageSize;

        // A good time to remove records greater than cache
        me.purgeRecords();

        // No more data to prefetch
        if (me.getCount() === me.getTotalCount() && !forceLoad) {
            return;
        }

        // Currently not requesting this page and range isn't already satisified
        if (Ext.Array.indexOf(me.pagesRequested, page) === -1 && !me.rangeSatisfied(start, end)) {
            me.pagesRequested.push(page);

            // Copy options into a new object so as not to mutate passed in objects
            options = Ext.apply({
                page     : page,
                start    : start,
                limit    : pageSize,
                callback : me.onWaitForGuarantee,
                scope    : me
            }, options);
            me.prefetch(options);
        }
    },

    // Fixes too big guaranteedEnd and forces load even if all data is there
    doSort: function() {
        var me = this;
        if (me.buffered) {
            me.prefetchData.clear();
            me.prefetchPage(1, {
                callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                    if (success) {
                        guaranteeRange = records.length < 100 ? records.length : 100
                        me.guaranteedStart = 0;
                        me.guaranteedEnd = 99; // should be more dynamic
                        me.loadRecords(Ext.Array.slice(records, 0, guaranteeRange));
                        me.unmask();
                    }
                }
            }, true);
            me.mask();
        }
    }
});   

Ext.override(Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature, {

    onBeforeLoad: Ext.emptyFn,

    // Appends the filter params, fixes too big guaranteedEnd and forces load even if all data is there
    reload: function() {
        var me = this,
            grid = me.getGridPanel(),
            filters = grid.filters.getFilterData(),
            store = me.view.getStore(),
            proxy = store.getProxy();

        store.prefetchData.clear();
        proxy.extraParams = this.buildQuery(filters);
        store.prefetchPage(1, {
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                if (success) {
                        guaranteeRange = records.length < 100 ? records.length : 100;
                        store.guaranteedStart = 0;
                        store.guaranteedEnd = 99; // should be more dynamic
                        store.loadRecords(Ext.Array.slice(records, 0, guaranteeRange));
                    store.unmask();
                }
            } 
        }, true);
        store.mask();
    }
});
```

My store is configured like so:

```
// the paged store of account data
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Account',
    remoteSort: true,
    buffered: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: '../list?name=accounts', //<-- supports remote filter and remote sort
        simpleSortMode: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },
    pageSize: 200
});
```

The grid is:

```
// the infinite scroll grid with filters
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    viewConfig: {
        trackOver: false,
        singleSelect: true,
    },
    features: [{
        ftype: 'filters',
        updateBuffer: 1000 // trigger load after a 1 second timer
    }],
    verticalScrollerType: 'paginggridscroller',
    invalidateScrollerOnRefresh: false,         
    // grid columns
    columns: [columns...],
});
```

Also the initial load must be done like this (not just store.load()):

```
store.prefetch({
    start: 0,
    limit: 200,
    callback: function() {
        store.guaranteeRange(0, 99);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your answer provided the right direction, I modified your code from

```
store.loadRecords(Ext.Array.slice(records, 0, count));
```

to

```
store.loadRecords(Ext.Array.slice(records, 0, records.length));
```

This fixed an issue of your previous filter returning empty results. After I inserted this change it was working correctly.

Comment: Good spot. I see what you are saying I think: when the store filters down to less than the guarantee range then the guarantee range sticks at that amount and wont load more. The problem with your solution though is that the guarantee range will become the same size as the store and it will not prefetch as a result, this means that when the grid is scrolled normally it will never reload once you get past row 200 or whatever the page size is. I added a solution into the override, it's just not very dynamic. The guaranteeRange variable I have set to a static 100 because that's what mine is.