# Customize buffered grid paging parameters

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I want to send my pagination parameter in the POST body instead of the urlParam. How can I do that? I have tried to search in sencha forum and many other place but cannot find any examples. Should I modify the prefetchPage function like this post? 
[ExtJS Infinite Scroll Grid with remote Filters and Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156541/extjs-infinite-scroll-grid-with-remote-filters-and-sort?rq=1)

I want instead of

> /serviceCall?start=0&limit=100&pageIndex=1

I want

> /serviceCall?

```
Body : 
{   
 "start" : 0,
 "limit" : 100,
 "pageIndex" : 1,
 "pagingId": uuid (some extra parameter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set:

- `actionMethods` - to set the request read should be done with `POST` method.
- `paramsAsJson` - to send parameter via form instead of url arguments
- `extraParams` - to set extra parameters (`pagingId`)
- `pageParam` - to change page parameter from default `page` to custom `pageIndex`

Example:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['a'],
    noCache: true,
    remoteSort: false,
    remoteFilter: false,
    pageSize: 10,
    proxy: {
        paramsAsJson: true,
        url: "https://example.xyz/f",
        noCache: false,
        type: 'ajax',
        pageParam: 'pageIndex',

        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        extraParams: {
            "pagingId": uuid //extra parameter
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hi thank you so much for your answer. But I have another question, if I want to pass the pagingId from my previous prefetched data. How to do that?

I mean, example
the returned data is :
{ 
   items: [],
   totalItems: 123,
   pagingID: uuid from backend
}

i want to pass this pagingID back to the service call.
I try to use the event store.on('prefetch'), but i cant find a way to access the data outside of the rootProperty. :(

Comment: You can get last params by `store.lastOptions.params`

Comment: sorry if what i try sounds dumb. I was told elasticSearch works that way. It needs the pagingID to know the sequence of page to returned. So, we try to pass the pagingID from backend to GUI then GUI pass it back to backend on every prefetch. (the pagingID will be different for every page)